# PHP imap_open Server bug: non-empty initial PLAIN challenge

Tags: php, imap

I have a piece of code that connect to an IMAP and download some emails attachments. All worked flawlessy until today, and I can't figure out why, this is the error

This is the code:

```
Server bug: non-empty initial PLAIN challenge
```

In my testing environment after modify the line, all works again but when I commit and update the official environment the errors is still there.

```
if ($this->mbox = imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password,NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'))) ) // I added the last 3 parameters and in local env all works again.
{
    imap_errors();
    return "OK";
}
```

Comment: Looks like your server is implementing SASL-PLAIN incorrectly or in a way that your library doesn't like.  Try disabling that as well as GSSAPI.

Comment: thanks. can you tell me some clue how to disable them? Because the code up here is already disabling the GSSAPI authenticator.

Comment: I think I did it! I'll post the answer...

Answer (score 1):

After looking for disable or modify the configuration on the server side I try to add this code to disable the PLAIN authentication and it worked!

So this is my final code. I know it's not so fancy to test the connection like this but...

```
    if ($this->mbox = imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password) )
    {
        return "OK";
    }elseif ($this->mbox = imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password,NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'))) {
        return "OK";
    }elseif ($this->mbox = imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password,NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN'))) {
        return "OK";
    }

return imap_last_error();
```